# Looking for a modern-rock song

Tags: identify-this-song, rock

There's a song I heard at the mall once that sort of reminded me of something similar to "Green day" here's what I remember,

- The song's chorus repeated something like "You don't wanna, you don't wanna know"
- The vocalist was a male
- The song sounded as if it was in either the 2000s or late 90s

Comment: [Welcome to Music Fans Stack Exchange](http://musicfans.stackexchange.com/tour). Here you can learn [how you can improve your question](http://meta.musicfans.stackexchange.com/a/368/1721) 
and increase your chances for find the music you're looking for.

Answer (score 3):

With your description, this looks like "Baby You Don't Wanna Know" by **Sum 41**.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QvhYD47tlcU